# Is it possible for current versions of icinga2 to configure nodes from master?

Tags: monitoring, icinga, icinga2

I've carefully read http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/cli-commands and see command `icinga2 repository service` which should allow to add or remove services.

But when i tried to use it like:

```
[root@D01mplaceAPI d01mplacefe01]# icinga2 repository service remove name=ping6 host=all
information/cli: Dumping changelog items to file '/var/lib/icinga2/repository/changes/1470133975.6282029-Service-d7535967c0481dbeb28afe542a40e2f0687f4fc5b5fc5abafacbd4c24ff0d9cf.change'
[root@D01mplaceAPI d01mplacefe01]# icinga2 repository commit
Changes to be committed:

Removing service 'ping6'
    host = "all"

warning/cli: Service 'ping6' does not exist.
```

it shows service again:

```
[root@D01mplaceAPI d01mplacefe01]# icinga2 repository service list
...
Service 'ping6' (on Host 'd01mplacess01')
...
```

How to remove services from all hosts from master?

Comment: The repository cli command is not what you're looking for. That was made available for managing bottom-up scenarios with node update-config but modern installations look different these days ("top-down"). I'd advise you to look into the cluster config sync mechanism from inside zones.d/ - updates on the master are immediately synced and reflected on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

so, for "Is it possible for current versions of icinga2 to configure nodes from master?"

Plugin https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2-module-director was built for configuring checks from web-master-node. And it works nice.

what about `icinga2 repository` - it is not for this purpose and on the Internet is very little information about that. (